HTMX Form in Gin Admin Panel Requires Page Reload to Resubmit Changes
I have a form on an admin panel I am working on that doesnt allow me to resubmit changes on it unless I reload the page. I am using HTMX, and GIN primarily:
Form:
<tr data-id="{{ .ID }}">
    <form id="update-vehicle-form-{{ .ID }}" action="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/update" hx-post="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/update" hx-target="closest tr" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        <td>{{ .ID }}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="brand-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Brand }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="model_name-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .ModelName }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="year-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Year }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="price-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Price }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="condition-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-select">
                <option value="new" {{ if eq .Condition "new" }}selected{{ end }}>New</option>
                <option value="used" {{ if eq .Condition "used" }}selected{{ end }}>Used</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><textarea name="description-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-textarea">{{ .Description }}</textarea></td>
        <td>
            <select name="status-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-select">
                <option value="available" {{ if eq .Status "available" }}selected{{ end }}>Available</option>
                <option value="sold" {{ if eq .Status "sold" }}selected{{ end }}>Sold</option>
                <option value="pending" {{ if eq .Status "pending" }}selected{{ end }}>Pending</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ if .Media }}
            {{ range .Media }}
            <div>
                <a href="{{ .FileURL }}" target="_blank">{{ .FileName }}</a>
                <button class="delete-media-btn" hx-delete="/admin/vehicles/media/{{ .ID }}/delete" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this media?" hx-target="this.parentNode" hx-swap="outerHTML">Delete</button>
            </div>
            {{ end }}
            {{ else }}
            No media available.
            {{ end }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="update-btn" >Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn" hx-delete="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/delete" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this vehicle?" hx-target="closest tr" hx-swap="outerHTML">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
{{ end }}

The update Handler:
    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "Brand":       c.PostForm("brand-" + c.Param("id")),
        "ModelName":   c.PostForm("model_name-" + c.Param("id")),
        "Year":        parseYear(c.PostForm("year-" + c.Param("id"))),
        "Price":       parsePrice(c.PostForm("price-" + c.Param("id"))),
        "Condition":   c.PostForm("condition-" + c.Param("id")),
        "Description": c.PostForm("description-" + c.Param("id")),
        "Status":      c.PostForm("status-" + c.Param("id")),
    }

    for key, value := range fields {
        if value != "" && value != 0.0 && value != nil {
            setField(vehicle, key, value)
        }
    }

    if vehicle.Status == "sold" {
        vehicle.DecisionDate = time.Now()
    } else if vehicle.Status == "available" || vehicle.Status == "pending" {
        vehicle.DecisionDate = time.Time{}
    }
}

func parseYear(yearStr string) int {
    year, _ := strconv.Atoi(yearStr)
    return year
}

func parsePrice(priceStr string) float64 {
    price, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(priceStr, 64)
    return price
}

func setField(vehicle *data.Vehicle, fieldName string, value interface{}) {
    switch fieldName {
    case "Brand":
        vehicle.Brand = value.(string)
    case "ModelName":
        vehicle.ModelName = value.(string)
    case "Year":
        vehicle.Year = value.(int)
    case "Price":
        vehicle.Price = value.(float64)
    case "Condition":
        vehicle.Condition = value.(string)
    case "Description":
        vehicle.Description = value.(string)
    case "Status":
        vehicle.Status = value.(string)
    }
}

func (vs *VehicleService) renderUpdatedVehicleRow(c *gin.Context, vehicle data.Vehicle) {
    var renderedRow bytes.Buffer
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("vehicle_row").ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates/admin/partials", "vehicle_row.html")))
    if err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(&renderedRow, "carRow", vehicle); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing partial template: %v", err)
        c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Internal Server Error")
        return
    }

    c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/html; charset=utf-8", renderedRow.Bytes())
}

how can I fix this so that no matter how many times i click update once something has changed on the form the request will be sent to the back end
I tried changing the form like this:
<tr data-id="{{ .ID }}">
    <form id="update-vehicle-form-{{ .ID }}" action="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/update" hx-post="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/update" hx-target="closest tr" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="my-custom-event from:form">
        <td>{{ .ID }}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="brand-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Brand }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="model_name-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .ModelName }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="year-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Year }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="price-{{ .ID }}" value="{{ .Price }}" class="edit-input"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="condition-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-select">
                <option value="new" {{ if eq .Condition "new" }}selected{{ end }}>New</option>
                <option value="used" {{ if eq .Condition "used" }}selected{{ end }}>Used</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><textarea name="description-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-textarea">{{ .Description }}</textarea></td>
        <td>
            <select name="status-{{ .ID }}" class="edit-select">
                <option value="available" {{ if eq .Status "available" }}selected{{ end }}>Available</option>
                <option value="sold" {{ if eq .Status "sold" }}selected{{ end }}>Sold</option>
                <option value="pending" {{ if eq .Status "pending" }}selected{{ end }}>Pending</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ if .Media }}
            {{ range .Media }}
            <div>
                <a href="{{ .FileURL }}" target="_blank">{{ .FileName }}</a>
                <button class="delete-media-btn" hx-delete="/admin/vehicles/media/{{ .ID }}/delete" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this media?" hx-target="this.parentNode" hx-swap="outerHTML">Delete</button>
            </div>
            {{ end }}
            {{ else }}
            No media available.
            {{ end }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="update-btn">Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn" hx-delete="/admin/vehicles/{{ .ID }}/delete" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this vehicle?" hx-target="closest tr" hx-swap="outerHTML">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
{{ end }}

and creating new events like this:

function initializeAdminFeatures() {
    console.log("Initializing Admin Features");

    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-btn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', toggleCollapsible);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('form[id^="update-vehicle-form-"]').forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            const customEventName = `my-custom-event-${Date.now()}`;
            setTimeout(() => {
                form.dispatchEvent(new Event(customEventName));
            }, 0);
        });
    });
}

function toggleCollapsible(event) {
    const content = event.target.nextElementSibling;

    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-content').forEach(c => {
        c.style.maxHeight = c === content ? (c.style.maxHeight ? null : `${c.scrollHeight}px`) : null;
    });

    console.log("Collapsible section toggled");
}


Isn't there any errors being logged at the server? Also, remove the action attribute as hx-post replaces it.

ok action removed and no there are no errors logged by the server it just acts like no changes were made to the page

Okay. What does the vehicle_row.html look like? It is seems like that's what you're returning after successful form submission?

its just returning the same row but with the updated information
